# Obter tamanho de uma requisição

Tags: node.js, express.js

No meu sistema, recebo vários request, gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de obter o tamanho desse request (`req`) recebido em `kbs` de preferencia, para ter uma noção de quanto foi gastado de banda para esse envio.

Comment: Está usando o express?

Comment: @jbueno estou sim

Answer (score 2):

É possível usar o módulo [request-stats](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-stats)

```
var requestStats = require('request-stats');
var stats = requestStats(server);

stats.on('complete', function (detalhes) {
    var tamanho = detalhes.req.bytes;
});
```

Perceba que a variável `tamanho` vai receber a quantidade de **bytes** da requisição, se você quiser apresentá-la em **Kbytes** só precisa dividir por 1024.

O objeto `detalhes` será é parecido com isso

```
{
    ok: true,             //Se a conexão foi fechada corretamente
    time: 0,              // O tempo (em ms) que foi levado para servir a requisição
    req: {
        bytes: 0,         // Quantidade de bytes da requisição
        headers: { ... }, // O headers HTTP da requisição
        method: 'POST',   // O método HTTP usado pelo client
        path: '...'       // O caminho da URL requisitada 
    },
    res  : {
        bytes: 0,         // Quantidade de bytes da resposta
        headers: { ... }, // Os headers da resposta
        status: 200       // O código HTTP da resposta 
    }
}
```

Existe também o *header* HTTP chamado **Content-Length**, porém, alguns clientes podem não enviar este *header* ou enviá-lo com um valor não verdadeiro.

Se você quiser usá-lo, pode obter o valor dele pela propriedade `headers` buscando a chave `content-length`.

```
var tamanho = req.headers['content-length'];
```

Comment: Pois é, usar Content-Length não é uma boa ideia. Sobre a biblioteca, estou em dúvida nesse `server`. Dentro de uma rota, como terei acesso a ele ?

Comment: Você quer usar isso apenas para uma rota específica?

Comment: Não, tens razão, faria mais sentido usar para todas. Porém, no express, eu não declaro explicitamente o server. Apenas realizo um `var port = process.env.PORT || 80;` e um `app.listen(port);`. Onde eu teria acesso a ele ?

Comment: Seguinte, @Jonathan Se você precisa usar em todas as requisições, vai ter que fazer tipo um "*middleware*" criando o objeto server `var http = require('http'); var server = http.createServer(app);`. Se quiser usar apenas em requisições específicas, pode capturar pelo `req.socket.server`

Comment: Fiz. Mas na parte `stats.on` ele passa direto, sem entrar no escopo.

Este `app` que estás criando o server, é o `var app = express();` certo ?

O valor de stats antes disso é: `EventEmitter {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined }
`